# Model using nested class in Spring boot using Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am studying to using Mongodb in Spring boot project. I feel confused about the question below:
My database structure is like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bea34f2931c9613a829c3f8"),
"name" : "hzb",
"sex" : "man",
"age" : 31,
"des" : "hzb_father",
"studentScore" : {
    "chinese" : "88",
    "english" : "93",
    "des" : "hzb_child"
},
```

}

and the model in code is like:

```
Class Student

private String name;
private String sex;
private Integer age;
private String des
private StudentScore studentScore;

    Setter getter....
```

---

```
Class StudentScore

private Integer Chinese;
private Integer English;
private String des;
```

Someone told me that use nested class is not a best practice for Java, and I use inherit class. So what are you thinking about this thought.

One more question. I want to insert some data in this database, so I want to write the code like this:

```
Student stu = new Student();
stu.setName("Trump");
stu.setSex("male");
stu.setAge("18");
stu.setDes("");
stu.setStudentScore(new StudentScore(){100,0,""});
```

Is there is a way to achieve the last line code without using constructer like C#?

Comment: who tells you inheritance is better than nested class?  read it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: why not to use a constractor like `stu.setStudentScore(new StudentScore(100,0,""));`